# @FetchRequest predicate not updating when UserDefaults value changes SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a SwiftUI `@FetchRequest` use a predicate only if a Boolean value stored in `UserDefaults` is `true` .

The issue is that the `FetchedResults` is not changing when the value for `showAvailable` changes. Currently I have to relaunch the app to see the `showAvailable` value based results.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@AppStorage("showAvailable") private var showAvailable : Bool = false


@FetchRequest private var list: FetchedResults<Item>



init() {
        @AppStorage("showAvailable") var showAvailable : Bool = false
        _list = FetchRequest(
            sortDescriptors: [],
            predicate: showAvailable ? NSPredicate(format: "parent == nil") : nil,
            animation: .default
        )
}

var body: some View {
     Button("Cancel") {
        showAvailable.toggle()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would update the fetch request with a new predicate in the Button action and that update should trigger the request to be executed again

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("showAvailable") private var showAvailable : Bool = false

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], 
                  predicate: NSPredicate(value: true)
                  animation: .default)
    private var list: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        Button("Cancel") {
            showAvailable.toggle()
            updatePredicate()
        }
        .onAppear {
            updatePredicate()
        }
    }

    private func updatePredicate() {
        if showAvailable {
            list.nspredicate = NSPredicate(format: "parent == nil")
        } else {
            list.nspredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly but now the struct is initialised not based on the `showAvailable` bool. Ideally I want the app to "remember" the `showAvailable` value when relaunching. Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: Move the whole `if showAvaliable...` section to a separate function and also call it from `.onAppear`